# Cannot setup Local Server via Divio Desktop App – "Service "web" failed to build

Tags: docker, wagtail, divio

While setting up for local development with "Python 3.5.x", "Wagtail" & "Blank Boilerplate" – The console returns an error

I'ved checked that docker command works, just not sure why I get the above error message.

Running Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.1

```
Creating workspace

cloning project repository
Cloning into '/Users/charlie/Django_projects/divio-project/test-project3'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '217.150.252.171' to the list of known hosts.
Locking the website...
remote: Counting objects: 64, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
Unlocking the website...

remote: Total 64 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (64/64), 14.86 KiB | 490.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), done.
downloading remote docker images
Pulling db  ... done
Pulling web ... done
building local docker images
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM aldryn/base-project:py3-3.23
 ---> c0f7353db6c7
Step 2/7 : ENV PIP_INDEX_URL=${PIP_INDEX_URL:-https://wheels.aldryn.net/v1/aldryn-extras+pypi/${WHEELS_PLATFORM:-aldryn-baseproject-py3}/+simple/}     WHEELSPROXY_URL=${WHEELSPROXY_URL:-https://wheels.aldryn.net/v1/aldryn-extras+pypi/${WHEELS_PLATFORM:-aldryn-baseproject-py3}/}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d0e665580f2
Step 3/7 : COPY requirements.* /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6de2503acd0c
Step 4/7 : COPY addons-dev /app/addons-dev/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36d866144ce1
Step 5/7 : RUN pip-reqs compile &&     pip-reqs resolve &&     pip install         --no-index --no-deps         --requirement requirements.urls
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 012d56b55012
Step 6/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> 44ca04bf2c80
Step 7/7 : RUN DJANGO_MODE=build python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
 ---> Running in 8f76702a142e
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 683, in main
    paths_in_sys = addsitepackages(paths_in_sys)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 282, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 204, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 173, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fix_certifi_hack.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi.old_where()
AttributeError: module 'certifi' has no attribute 'old_where'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c DJANGO_MODE=build python manage.py collectstatic --noinput' returned a non-zero code: 1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

There was an error trying to run a command. This is most likely
not an issue with divio-cli, but the called program itself.
Try checking the output of the command above.
The command was:
  docker-compose -f /Users/charlie/Django_projects/divio-project/test-project3/docker-compose.yml build
```

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Added Project on Divio Website (Python 3.5.x, Wagtail, Blank Boilerplate)
2. Downloaded and installed Divio Desktop App for Mac
3. Opened the Added project
4. Clicked on "Setup" (Local Server)
5. Terminal popped up, then ran the code above
6. Error Message: ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c DJANGO_MODE=build python manage.py collectstatic --noinput' returned a non-zero code: 1

Thanks.

Comment: The real error seems to be `File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fix_certifi_hack.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi.old_where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it looks like there is some code that has been deprecated in the Certifi package:
https://pypi.org/project/certifi/#history

And a new version was released at the end of last week.

To fix this simply force the version of the package you are using to `2018.10.15` by adding the following to the bottom of your requirements file:

```
certifi==2018.10.15
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works. Additionally, message from support suggested to add 
`certifi<2018.11.29`  to bottom of requirements.in file.